# How can I make my routers interconnected?

Tags: networking, router, wireless-router, ping, subnet

I work in a small business that has seven of the same routers around the building, which means seven SSIDs. What I am wondering is, is there anyway to make them interconnected so that they can communicate with each other?

When you connect to Router 1, your IP is 10.0.5.*

When you connect to Router 2, your IP is 10.0.6.*

When I try to ping a device connected to another router it does not work. Is there anyway to fix this? Our routers are TP-Link N600 Wireless Dual Band.

Here's the manual if it helps http://www.tp-link.com/Resources/document/TL-WDR3600_V1_user_guide.pdf

Comment: Sounds like they may all run a dhcp server each. Make sure to disable all but one, and you'll probably fix most of your issues.

Comment: If you don't have a reason to split the networks up (i.e. you want all IP addresses to be on the 10.0.5.* subnet), set 1 N600 as a router as the DHCP server. Connect the other N600 as switches (i.e. LAN to LAN), and disable the DHCP server. At this point, you can keep the 7 different SSIDs or make them all the same.

Comment: How are they hooked up now? What are they all connected to, and how?

Comment: I have tried turning off the DHCP and it doesn't seem to work. I did it on two of the routers and had one device connected to each. I then tried to get both devices to ping themselves with no success. One device's ip was 30.1.1.113 and the other one was 30.1.1.115

Comment: @DavidSchwartz They are all hooked up by the ethernet ports on the walls in the rooms

Comment: @fhgfyfgyydsyfdffdg That doesn't tell me much. What are those ethernet ports connections to?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest enabling the WDS Bridging feature.  (See  [TP-Link N600 Wireless Dual Band manual, page 43](http://www.tp-link.com/Resources/document/TL-WDR3600_V1_user_guide.pdf#page=43) and page 44.)  As fideli's comment indicates, you're likely best off using just one subnet, and I think you may also be best off using one SSID (matching all other routers).

Regarding Jonno's comment, it is true that there is some danger about having more than one DHCP server, if the DHCP servers could give out the same address, which implies that the DHCP servers don't cooperate with each other (by communicating with each other about what addresses are given out).  Traditionally DHCP servers have not cooperated with each other, but some newer products are supporting such a feature.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add a static route to the other network on each of them.

Do you have these options on your router?

- Advanced Routing
- Static Routing

How did you connect the 2 routers?
(If you connect the LAN port of one with the WAN port of the other I think that it might work. Because the router with the WAN port connected will add a routing between the 2 networks, and if this is the "Default Gateway" router - {on the other one} it will work.)

---

Static Routing Help
A static route is a pre-determined path that network information must follow to reach a specific host or network. Use the Static Routing page to add or delete a route.

To add static routing entries:

- Click the Add New... button.
- Enter the following data:

  - Destination Network - The Destination IP Address is the address of the network  or host that you want to assign to a static route.
  - Subnet Mask - The Subnet Mask determines which portion of an IP address is the network portion, and which portion is the host portion.
  - Default Gateway - This is the IP address of the default gateway device that allows for the contact between the Router and the network or host.
  - Select the Enabled in the Status pull-down list.
  - Click the Save button to save the changes.